# Custom TextBox with part of fixed content

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to create a custom TextBox in WPF and the textbox will have some digit and the string "% Per Annum" like "55% Per Annum". The user should be able to alter only the digit from the textbox, I want to keep the string "% Per Annum" as uneditable. Please help me.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty non-standard UI, and thus (relatively) expensive. Is there no way that the unit can live outside the textbox in a more platform-standard manner?

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you can modify the template of a control to completely change the appearance while keeping the functionality. In your case you can modify the control template of a `TextBox` by adding some extra text inside the border of the control.

In Visual Studio add a `TextBox` to your XAML. Then in the **Document Outline** you can right click the `TextBox` and select **Edit Template** => **Edit a Copy...**. A `Style` for a `TextBox` is then added to your XAML including a copy of the `ControlTemplate` used by the default `TextBox`. You can then modify the template as you like.

The main part of the `TextBox` is the `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListBoxChrome` border. To get the result you desire you can wrap the `ScrollViewer` inside a `Grid` with two columns and then place a `TextBlock` with the text "% Per Annum" in the second column. You probably also want to right align the text in the `TextBox` and you can do that by default by setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Right` in the `Style` of the `TextBox`.

Here is a complete sample XAML where I have added some comments to show where I made the edits:

```
<Window
  x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
      <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="PerAnnumTextBoxStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
      <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
      <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
      <!-- New setter -->
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
              <!-- ScrollViewer wrapped in a Grid -->
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,1"> % Per Annum</TextBlock>
              </Grid>
            </Themes:ListBoxChrome>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
          </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="50" Style="{StaticResource PerAnnumTextBoxStyle}" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and in my opionion better way is to put the text box inside a `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyTextProperty}"/>
    <Label Content="55% Per Annum" />
</StackPanel>
```